# Create AAC file programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, aac

I am creating an iOS app that can play instrument sounds.
The user can play and record his melody.
Now, I need some help to export his record into an AAC file.

Any idea ?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a great project that does exactly that by Michael Tayson](http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-aac-compressed-audio-conversion-on-ios/)

Answer (score 0):

you could think about starting with LPCM and then convert this down to AAC.

Have a look at Apple's 'Audio Converter Services Reference' specifically the following:

```
AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer
```